# excel: most repeated value if a value exists in another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| Accont | payment |
| -------- | -------------- |
| 568P45 | 42.5 |
| 145K58 |  |
| 568p45 | 12.5 |
| 158K58 |  |
| 568p45 | 12 |
| 145KL8 | 13 |
| 568p45 | 19 |
| 145K58 | 14 |
| 5863HJ |  |
| 578p45 | 15 |
| 145K58 |  |
| 568p45 | 18 |
| 145K58 | 12 |
| 145K58 |  |
| 145K58 |  |

Column A contains the account numbers and B contains the value paid( some are blank as in not paid) How can I find the account with most paid and unpaid claims?  thanks ahead

Comment: What version of Excel do you have?

Comment: Microsoft professional plus 2019

Comment: most by COUNT (an excel function) or most by SUM (another excel function.  both can get you at the answer depending on the answer you're looking for...

Comment: @sous2817 how can I combine rows get the answer? Im not sure how to use COUNTIF because each cell contains a different value

Comment: easiest would be to make a list of the unique values on another sheet and follow the instructions here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/countif-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34

Comment: It was much easier to use Pivot table and find it. Thanks anyways for your time:)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you, to use [PivotTable](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576) to organize and review your data.

A PivotTable is a powerful tool to calculate, summarize, and analyze data that lets you see comparisons, patterns, and trends in your data.